# By default in which file system does spark look for reading file?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run spark in standalone mode on CentOs, and trying to read text file from local file system using

```
scala > var text = sc.textFile("/home/Documents/test.txt")
```

but it is giving exception -

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

But when I am changing the code as :

```
 scala > var text = sc.textFile("file:///home/Documents/test.txt")
```

I am able to read it.
My question is :

when  tried reading file without file:///, is it looking the file in HDFS file system ? and it yes then is HDFS is default FS where spark search for the file ?